# Can somebody give me a technique to power a laptop with AC to DC supply with connection to laptop battery pins

Tags: integrated-circuit, battery-charging, laptop

It's my first question here please bare my language and long paragraphs.

I have this lenovo R400 it was running without battery for 7 years. All of a sudden it turned off and didn't show any activity.

I tried all the possible ways to connect with DC plug. Checked the plug,  wire and voltage; and everything is alright. Then I took it to a repairing guy, whom I trust, to check it thoroughly.  He came up with repairing strategy but gave me 0% guarantee that it would be successful (and there's 99.99% of it becoming dead).

I can't lose this computer. So, I bought new battery and it's running with it, but problem now is that it doesn't charge. It has lost the ability to charge as it does not detect DC plug.

I connected 12v 2.5A DC pins directly to battery junctions but it charges very slowly.  It takes 10 hours to charge for 36% and then it gets stable at 36%. However, the laptop consumes more power and the battery drains in 2 hours even with the DC input still connected.

The battery output voltage is 11.1v and its 49Wh with 6 cells. I attached a picture of outputs from battery. I don't know if its series terminal outputs or resistance varied voltage or resistance.

[image]

If there's anybody who can suggest battery terminal outputs and resistance so that I can mock a battery it'll be helpful.

---

There is no concern of data or anything like that, i just want it to run so i can donate it to needy students. I already mentioned about charger and plug its alright. I just need to know if this hypothesis works or not. Consider it as experiment. We need to find a way I'll update if i got succeed please enlighten me with  your knowledge so that it becomes handy of there's any way to mock a battery. That's all!

---

The dock station also use same charging ic so it's not working anymore.
i left it connected for another 8-10 hours with a 7.2Ah Pb acid battery+ 16v DC supply in parallel circuit and it acheived 90% of battery backup.

Comment: Did the charger plug get warm? Hot? Direct connection probably fails to communicate battery OEM charger code to MOBO.

Comment: If you can't lose the computer, it's about time you backed it up.

Comment: Charge the battery to 36% one more time, and backup the disk!

Comment: Figure it out from the schematics. If the plug/jack was ever hot, fix it.  Use authentic batteries with AC/DC code.  Figure it out https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6IqcVTk0jpYTnBpX19mUmcteVU/view

Comment: If it is data you don't want to lose, and not the laptop, you can usually remove the harddisk and attach it to a USB adapter and connect it to any PC as an external hard drive. Sometimes even adapter is not required if you can connect a sata cable and power cable.

Comment: does it have a docking station connector with several dozen pins? Two+ of those pins will have continuity with your DC port. Seems simpler than hacking the battery, if it's an option at least...

Comment: Page 54 of the T400/R400 hardware maintenance manual says "If the backup battery discharges quickly after replacement, replace the system board." The manual is freely available online. From personal experience, I would first check the electrolytic capacitors.